# Return result based on two results set based on Id, irrespective of rows count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm receiving data set from two different sources `@Table1, @Table2`, both the tables has `Id` columns. For the same Id, both sources return a different number of records.

I want to combine the result based on the `@MainTable`, it has all the possible Ids from `@Table1` and `@Table2`. If the other table doesn't have the same number of records then it can be applied with `NULL`.

**Sample data and table design:**

```
DECLARE @MainTable TABLE (Id INT, [Name] VARCHAR (50));
INSERT INTO @MainTable (Id, [Name]) VALUES (1, 'One'), (2, 'Two'), (3, 'Three');

DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (Id INT, Val1 INT, Val2 INT);
INSERT INTO @Table1 (Id, Val1, Val2) VALUES 
(1, 11, 12), (1, 22, 23), (1, 33, 34), (1, 38, 39), 
(2, 31, 32), (2, 34, 35), 
(3, 44, 45);

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (Id INT, Val3 INT, Val4 INT);
INSERT INTO @Table2 (Id, Val3, Val4) VALUES 
(1, 20, 21), (1, 25, 26), 
(2, 30, 31), (2, 33, 34), (2, 36, 37), (2, 38, 39), (2, 40, 41),
(3, 51, 52), (3, 54, 55), (3, 56, 57), (3, 58, 59);
```

**Expected output:**

| Id | Name | Val1 | Val2 | Val3 | Val4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | One | 11 | 12 | 20 | 21 |
| 1 | One | 22 | 23 | 25 | 26 |
| 1 | One | 33 | 34 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | One | 38 | 39 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | Two | 31 | 32 | 30 | 31 |
| 2 | Two | 34 | 35 | 33 | 34 |
| 2 | Two | NULL | NULL | 36 | 37 |
| 2 | Two | NULL | NULL | 38 | 39 |
| 2 | Two | NULL | NULL | 40 | 41 |
| 3 | Three | 44 | 55 | 51 | 52 |
| 3 | Three | NULL | NULL | 54 | 55 |
| 3 | Three | NULL | NULL | 56 | 57 |
| 3 | Three | NULL | NULL | 58 | 59 |

I'm using SQL Server 2012. I have tried some code as below, but those are not helped:

```
SELECT MT.Id, MT.[Name], A.Val1, A.Val2, B.Val3, B.Val4
FROM @MainTable MT
OUTER APPLY ( SELECT * FROM @Table1 T1 WHERE T1.Id = MT.Id ) A
OUTER APPLY ( SELECT * FROM @Table2 T2 WHERE T2.Id = MT.Id ) B

SELECT *
FROM @MainTable MT
LEFT OUTER JOIN @Table1 T1 ON T1.Id = MT.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN @Table2 T2 ON T2.Id = MT.Id
```

Comment: What in your data defines that the row in `Table1` with the values `11` and `12` is related to the row in `Table2` with the values `20` and `21`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading between to lines, but if you don't care which rows join to which (as I see no relationship between the rows in `@Table1` to `@Table2`) you could do something like this:

```sql
WITH T1 AS(
    SELECT T1.Id,
           T1.Val1,
           T1.Val2,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.Id ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN --Define your ORDER BY properly here
    FROM @Table1 T1),
T2 AS(
    SELECT T2.Id,
           T2.Val3,
           T2.Val4,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T2.Id ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN --Define your ORDER BY properly here
    FROM @Table2 T2),
RNs AS(
    SELECT T1.Id,
           T1.RN
    FROM T1
    UNION
    SELECT T2.Id,
           T2.RN
    FROM T2)
SELECT MT.Id,
       T1.Val1,
       T1.Val2,
       T2.Val3,
       T2.Val4
FROM @MainTable MT
     JOIN RNs ON MT.Id = RNs.Id
     LEFT JOIN T1 ON RNs.Id = T1.ID
                 AND RNs.RN = T1.RN
     LEFT JOIN T2 ON RNs.Id = T2.ID
                 AND RNs.RN = T2.RN;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8a8f1e992136c03f82e0f4b5668f1f0c)

Comment: You could have just edited that for me, @GordonLinoff . You knew what I meant. :)

Comment: @Larnu Let me try this and confirm you.

Answer (score 1):

Larnu beat me to it. But I'm still posting my answer too as I think mine will be a little bit faster if the dataset grows larger.

```
DECLARE @MainTable TABLE (Id INT, [Name] VARCHAR (50));
INSERT INTO @MainTable (Id, [Name]) VALUES (1, 'One'), (2, 'Two'), (3, 'Three');

DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (Id INT, Val1 INT, Val2 INT);
INSERT INTO @Table1 (Id, Val1, Val2) VALUES 
(1, 11, 12), (1, 22, 23), (1, 33, 34), (1, 38, 39), 
(2, 31, 32), (2, 34, 35), 
(3, 44, 45);

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (Id INT, Val3 INT, Val4 INT);
INSERT INTO @Table2 (Id, Val3, Val4) VALUES 
(1, 20, 21), (1, 25, 26), 
(2, 30, 31), (2, 33, 34), (2, 36, 37), (2, 38, 39), (2, 40, 41),
(3, 51, 52), (3, 54, 55), (3, 56, 57), (3, 58, 59);


with cte1 as (
    select
        t1.*,
        row_number() over (partition by t1.Id order by t1.Val1) as seqno 
    from @Table1 t1
),
cte2 as (
    select
        t2.*,
        row_number() over (partition by t2.Id order by t2.Val3) as seqno 
    from @Table2 t2
),
cte3 as (
    select isnull(c1.Id, c2.Id) as Id, c1.Val1, c1.Val2, c2.Val3, c2.Val4
    from cte1 c1
        full outer join cte2 c2 on (c2.Id = c1.Id and c2.seqno = c1.seqno)
)
select
    m.Id,
    m.[Name],
    c3.Val1,
    c3.Val2,
    c3.Val3,
    c3.Val4
from @MainTable m
    left outer join cte3 c3 on (c3.Id = m.Id);
```